# Numerically (or analytically) solve integro-differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, integro-differential-equations

Excuse me in advance in case of inaccuracies, I am absolutely not familiar with such a type of integro-differential equations. Let us consider the following equation
$$
\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} = g(t) + \lambda \int\limits_{- \infty}^{t} F\left(t, t', y(t), y(t'), \frac{dy(t)}{dt}, \frac{dy(t')}{dt}\right) dt',
$$
where $\lambda \in \mathrm{R}$, and $g$ is a smooth function. There also known a solution for $t<0$ which reads: $y(t) = h(t)$ (here $h(t)$ is a known function). The problem is to solve the second-order integro-differential equation for $t > 0$.

In my case, I do not believer it can be solved analytically.
Talking about the numerical approach, I would typically act in the following way: first, approximate the integral with finite sums formulas, such as rectangular, trapezoidal, Simpson, or else; second, approximate the function $y(t)$ with finite difference method, obtain the system of linear equations and solve it by preferable method. I understand how to make something like this in the case of the integral with fixed ends, but have no idea how to implement it in the described problem.

I would be very glad for any recommendations/solutions/references (preferably, not for specialists in numerical methods, which I will be able to understand).

Comment: Just for curiosity : what kind of concrete functions $F$ shall you consider ?

Comment: I would assume you can use the Python package [idesolver](https://idesolver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Alternatively, maybe you can rewrite the equation into a boundary value problem, see [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41201/2nd-order-differential-equation-coupled-to-integro-differential-equation-in-pyth) for an example on scicomp.